# My ethereum wallet transactions not going through

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet

Hi I know this has been asked but I used my ethereum wallet to do a test transaction I moved the gas slider all the way up and my transaction still has been processing for over 5 hours..am I doing something wrong? What can I check?..https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5b6f64f0577d13fb85b877c970094867980be39e0d834da302f429e0e8ef6857 ..Can someone give me some advice? Thanks guys

Comment: There's not much anyone can do, you simply have to wait.

Comment: I guess my question is does the transaction look like it's setup correctly? If I have to wait that's ok..just want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That transaction uses a nonce of 1, which won't be the correct nonce until this transaction goes through: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7f5228d4b3ec15c01af0c2fd53bb9112f60a161197937665561b9b19810d88a5.

That earlier transaction used a gas price of 20 gwei, so although it's taking longer than I would have expected, it's not super surprising yet.

The new transaction should go through fairly quickly after that (quite possibly in the same block), since you provided a gas price of 80 gwei, which should get your transaction in very quickly.

Comment: That other transaction has been restarting since early this morning..that's normal? Do transactions wait for the one before it to process first? Sorry for the newbie question

Comment: Yes, transactions need to be processed in order. They each have a sequence number known as a "nonce" (number used once). You can *replace* an earlier transaction by submitting a new one with the same nonce as the old one (and a higher gas price so it gets picked up instead), but transactions with higher nonces simply have to wait their turn.

Comment: That totally makes sense then because my first transaction had such a low gas once that gets picked up I should good to go..I thought I some how messed my node up and it was sending bad transactions ..you are awesome!

Comment: Happy to help! I'd say just wait it out now, though if you're in a hurry, there are tools to help "cancel" (replace) the slow transaction.